# How to trim array to show only non duplicated values?

Tags: php, arrays

I'm struggling with the array results:

```
$result = Db::getInstance()->ExecuteS( $sql ); 

    $this->smarty->assign( array(
         'result' => $result
    ));
```

This is my array:

```
Array ( 
[0] => Array ( [id_tag] => 2 [id_post] => 5 [id_smart_blog_post_shop] => 5 [id_smart_blog_post] => 5 [id_shop] => 1 [id_lang] => 1 [name] => Microchip ) 
[1] => Array ( [id_tag] => 2 [id_post] => 6 [id_smart_blog_post_shop] => 6 [id_smart_blog_post] => 6 [id_shop] => 1 [id_lang] => 1 [name] => Microchip ) 
[2] => Array ( [id_tag] => 2 [id_post] => 7 [id_smart_blog_post_shop] => 7 [id_smart_blog_post] => 7 [id_shop] => 1 [id_lang] => 1 [name] => Microchip ) 
[3] => Array ( [id_tag] => 2 [id_post] => 8 [id_smart_blog_post_shop] => 8 [id_smart_blog_post] => 8 [id_shop] => 1 [id_lang] => 1 [name] => Microchip ) 
[4] => Array ( [id_tag] => 2 [id_post] => 9 [id_smart_blog_post_shop] => 9 [id_smart_blog_post] => 9 [id_shop] => 1 [id_lang] => 1 [name] => Microchip ) 
[5] => Array ( [id_tag] => 4 [id_post] => 10 [id_smart_blog_post_shop] => 10 [id_smart_blog_post] => 10 [id_shop] => 1 [id_lang] => 1 [name] => XPPower ) 
[6] => Array ( [id_tag] => 2 [id_post] => 11 [id_smart_blog_post_shop] => 11 [id_smart_blog_post] => 11 [id_shop] => 1 [id_lang] => 1 [name] => Microchip ) 
[7] => Array ( [id_tag] => 2 [id_post] => 12 [id_smart_blog_post_shop] => 12 [id_smart_blog_post] => 12 [id_shop] => 1 [id_lang] => 1 [name] => Microchip ) 
[8] => Array ( [id_tag] => 4 [id_post] => 13 [id_smart_blog_post_shop] => 13 [id_smart_blog_post] => 13 [id_shop] => 1 [id_lang] => 1 [name] => XPPower ) 
)
```

and, what I want is to show name values only once like:

```
Microchip, XPPower
```

and not like this:

```
Microchip, Microchip, Microchip, Microchip, Microchip, XPPower, Microchip, Microchip, XPPower
```

I'm trying to use `array_unique` to show only non duplicate values, but it works partially and shows only.

`Microchip` value once and leaves `XPPower`:

```
$tags = Db::getInstance()->ExecuteS( $sql ); 
$result = array_values(array_unique($tags));

$this->smarty->assign( array(
     'result' => $result
));
```

array printed:

```
Array ( 
 [0] => Array ( [id_tag] => 2 [id_post] => 5 [id_smart_blog_post_shop] => 5 [id_smart_blog_post] => 5 [id_shop] => 1 [id_lang] => 1 [name] => Microchip ) 
 )
```

This is $sql function if someone want to know

```
$sql = 'SELECT * FROM '._DB_PREFIX_.'smart_blog_post_tag p INNER JOIN 
            '._DB_PREFIX_.'smart_blog_post_shop s ON p.id_post=s.id_smart_blog_post AND s.id_shop = '.(int) Context::getContext()->shop->id.' INNER JOIN 
            '._DB_PREFIX_.'smart_blog_tag t ON p.id_tag= t.id_tag where t.id_lang = '.(int)$id_lang.' LIMIT '.$limit;
```

Comment: *i want is to show name values only once* - and what about other columns?

Comment: only name values are essential for me. other values are not shown in module frontend

Comment: You can try ```GROUP by name``` in your sql query if you dont need other values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$names = array();
foreach ($tags as $tag) {
    $names[$tag['name']] = 1;
}
print_r(array_keys($names));
```

Comment: This code works perfectly and it's 100% answer to my question. It's broke my smarty variables but it's not releated with this question. So +1 from me :)

Answer (score 0):

Couldn't you use a second array to catch the unique results? Like:

```
$uniq_results=array();
foreach ($results as $r) {
    if (!in_array($r["name"],$uniq_results)) {
        $uniq_results[]=$r["name"];
    }
} unset($r);

var_dump($uniq_results);
// should print only the unique values
```